# Getting a Malloc Error when trying to write Unity iOS plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

Trying to write a quick Unity plugin to get data off of the clipboard, the function in question is as follows:

```
extern "C"
    {
        const char * _importString()
        {
            UIPasteboard *result = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
            NSString * resultString = [result string];
            return [resultString UTF8String];
        }
    }
```

However it is giving me the following error when I activate the function:

```
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A9 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2017.1.0f3 (472613c02cf7)
2017-08-26 13:46:21.395230+0100 ProductName[8608:2930827] [Common] _BSMachError: port 5e03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2017-08-26 13:46:21.400889+0100 ProductName[8608:2930827] [Common] _BSMachError: port 5e03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
UnloadTime: 4.034333 ms
ProductName(8608,0x1b8100b40) malloc: *** error for object 0x1740a6191: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Mainly writing in Unity C sharp so have little knowledge of iOS plugins and no clue where to start, any help appreciated.

EDIT:

For those of you playing along at home here is the relevant Unity snippet:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern string _importString();

//retrieves the clipboard contents from xcode
public string iPhoneImportClipboard()
{
    return _importString();
}
```

Comment: You should probably post the C# side of the code too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `-string` must not be treated as a malloc’d pointer.

You need to `malloc` a buffer and `strcpy` said string prior to returning it.

---

```
extern "C"
    {
        const char * _importString()
        {
            UIPasteboard *result = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
            NSString * resultString = [result string];
            return strdup([resultString UTF8String]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi sorry, been away all weekend thanks for you answer. Objective C is really not my wheelhouse, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It isn't an obj-c issue;  it is a straight C issue.

Comment: Besides the missing bracket that works perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: @thoxey Fixed. Thanks.